# Can't disable mod_security rule on apache

Tags: apache, sql-injection, mod-security

If I post data of a form on my website, I keep getting this error in the log file.

```
[Thu Jul 16 09:45:25 2020] [error] [client 85.1.202.234] ModSecurity: Access denied with 
code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?i:\\bor\\b ?(?:\\d{1,10}|[\\'"][^=]{1,10}[\\'"]) ?[=. 
<>]+|(?i:'\\s+x?or\\s+.{1,20}[+\\-!<>=])|\\b(?i:x?or)\\b\\s+(\\d{1,10}|'[^=]{1,10}')|\\b(? 
i:x?or)\\b\\s+(\\d{1,10}|'[^=]{1,10}')\\s*[=<>])" at ARGS:tx_testzentraleshop_pi1[address]. 
[file "/etc/apache2/crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line 
"134"] [id "959071"] [rev "2.2.5"] [msg "SQL Injection Attack"] [data "or 1"] [severity 
"CRITICAL"] [tag "WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-19"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] 
[tag "OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [hostname "xy.xxxx.com"] [uri 
"/tests/panier-dachat/flexShow/buy/"] [unique_id "XxAFlVvHYlQAADKCJLYAAABH"]
```

I tried to disable the rule 959071 in different ways in the config file. But none of them actually worked. I always got the same error message again.

I tried these configurations:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 959071
</IfModule>

<IfModule security2_module>
  SecRuleRemoveById 959071        
</IfModule>

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginswith "/tests/panier-dachat/flexShow/buy/ "id:959071,phase:2,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveById=959071"
```

After every change I restarted the apache webserver.
Can someone explain me why they didn't work? How can I disable the rule?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708385/modsecurity-access-denied-with-code-403

Answer (score 0):

`SecRuleRemoveById` needs to be specified AFTER the rule it’s removing in the config, not before.